# compare formatted date vba

Tags: excel, vba

hi have to compare 2 date variables´.
One of them is from a general field cell and i store it into a String variable.
The other one is taken from a data field and i store it into a Date variable.
The procedure i follow is:
-i take the first data, the one in the normal field that is in this format "(5-8-2014)" and i work on it in the following procedure:

```
tempdate1 = Cells(27, "N").Value:
tempdate1 = Replace(tempdate1, "(", ""):
tempdate1 = Replace(tempdate1, ")", ""):
tempdate1 = Format(tempdate1, "DD-MM-YYYY"):
```

i read all the column A with a for to search the string "TIMESTAMP" and take the related date column next to it.

-Highest date is the maximun date, and at the beginning it takes value from tempdate
-countdate is a variable to count the number of date i want (i want to count a date only if the date i found is greater then the local maximun)
-if temp>date1 i found a local MAXIMUM, i count the TIMESTAMP and i put date in the array.

```
 highestDate = tempdate1
countdate = 1 ' because i have already the first date
k = 0
dates(k) = highestDate ' i put in the first position the first data
'Find the highest Date
For i = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "TIMESTAMP" Then
temp = Cells(i, 4).Value:
temp = Format(temp, "MM-DD-YYYY"):
date1 = CDate(highestDate):
    If temp > date1 Then: date1 = temp: countdate = countdate + 1: highestDate = date1:
dates(k) = highestDate: k = k + 1
End If
Next i
```

Problem is that the procedure is not getting inside the if and i have no elements on the array even if in the excel sheet i have several dates greater than the first one that i found.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ok, time to learn some very basic debugging like stepping through your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While VBA allows the colon, continuation character, it is generally not recommened.  Example, debugging is difficult when using the colons as you can't set breakpoints.

Please set a breakpoint on

```
   dates(k) = highestDate
```

When you debug, you'll see it's how you're setting the bounds of the array:

```
dim dates(0)
highestDate = tempdate1
countdate = 1 ' because i have already the first date
k = 0
dates(k) = highestDate ' i put in the first position the first data
'Find the highest Date
For i = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "TIMESTAMP" Then
temp = Cells(i, 4).Value:
temp = Format(temp, "MM-DD-YYYY"):
date1 = CDate(highestDate):
    If temp > date1 Then: date1 = temp: countdate = countdate + 1: highestDate = date1:
        dates(k) = highestDate 
        k = k + 1
        REDIM PRESERVE dates(k) 'make room in the array!
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you, with the new changes it says "array already dimensioned".

Comment: Now the array it's working, i just put REDIM PRESERVE before put data "in the room" that acctually sounds good :) Thank you very much.